# Find instance of equation that also minimizes one variable

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I want to find an instance of solution of a very complicated equation like

```
func[a, x, y, w, z] == c
```

that is a global minimum (within the solution set) of a.

Below is a minimum working example

```
Alfa = 1/137;
sw = Sqrt[0.23152];
mμ = 105.658*10^-3 (*GeV*);

Γμ = 1/(3.34*10^18);

gs = 1;
gU = 1/Sqrt[2] Sqrt[4  Pi Alfa]/sw;

BRfunction[MU_, Ms_, VU11_, VU12_, VU21_, O11_, O12_, O21_] := 
  (1/Γμ)*
    (mμ^5 (1/
       5 gs^4 MU^4 O11^2 (15 Ms^2 - 2 mμ^2) (O12^2 + O21^2) + 
       4 gs^2 gU^2 Ms^4 MU^2 O11 VU11 (O12 VU21 + O21 VU12) + 
       2 gU^4 Ms^6 VU11^2 (VU12^2 + VU21^2)))/(6144 π^3 Ms^6 MU^4);

FindInstance[
  BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, O21] == 10^(-12) && 
  MU > 100 && MU < 100000 && Ms > 100 && Ms < 100000 && O11 > -1 && 
  O11 < 1 && O12 > -1 && O12 < 1 && O21 > -1 && O21 < 1 && O11 != 0 &&
  VU11 > -1 && VU11 < 1 && VU11 != 0 && VU12 > -1 && VU12 < 1 && 
  VU21 > -1 && VU21 < 1 && VU21 <= Sqrt[1 - VU11^2] && 
  VU12 <= Sqrt[1 - VU11^2], 
  {MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, O21}]
```

But I don't want to find *any* instance, as the code would output, I want to find the instance that minimizes MU.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

**Edit**:

Following the first answer suggestion, I have done

```
FindInstance[
  BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, O21] == 10^(-12) && 
  MU > 100 && MU < 100000 && Ms > 100 && Ms < 100000 && O11 > -1 && 
  O11 < 1 && O12 > -1 && O12 < 1 && O21 > -1 && O21 < 1 && O11 != 0 &&
  VU11 > -1 && VU11 < 1 && VU11 != 0 && VU12 > -1 && VU12 < 1 && 
  VU21 > -1 && VU21 < 1 && VU21 <= Sqrt[1 - VU11^2] && 
  VU12 <= Sqrt[1 - VU11^2], 
  {MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, O21}]
```

but evaluating

```
  BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, O21]
```

using the set of variables given as solution by `NMinimize` with `Method -> Automatic` and `PrecisionGoal -> 20` (and a little different constraints such as `Abs[VU11]>0.1` which are definitely not relevant to the problem) I don't get the expected result of `10^(-12)`, but rather, at best, something to the order of `10^(-9)`.

Comment: Far too few details to even give you a suggestion. Can you make a simpler example (a Minimal Working Example, MWE) that represents what you are trying to do?

Comment: `func[a_, x_, y_, w_, z_, c_] = a*x*y*w*z - c;
NMinimize[{a, func[a, x, y, w, z, c] == 0}, {a, x, y, z, w, c}, 
 Method -> Automatic]`

Comment: @MarcoB I have added a MWE!

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `NMinimize` or `FindMinimum`, specifying the "instance" qualifications as constraints?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried it, but then the required equation (enforced as a constraint) does not hold as expected. The issue is a little more detailed in the edited question.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe as below.

```
NMinimize[{MU, 
  BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, O21] == 10^(-12) && 
   MU > 100 && MU < 100000 && Ms > 100 && Ms < 100000 && O11 > -1 && 
   O11 < 1 && O12 > -1 && O12 < 1 && O21 > -1 && O21 < 1 && O11 != 0 &&
    VU11 > -1 && VU11 < 1 && VU11 != 0 && VU12 > -1 && VU12 < 1 && 
   VU21 > -1 && VU21 < 1 && VU21 <= Sqrt[1 - VU11^2] && 
   VU12 <= Sqrt[1 - VU11^2]}, {MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, 
  O21}]
```

Comment: I had to unaccept your answer by the reason added to the question. I upliked it for now!

Comment: To @GaloisFan and @cvgmt  Do your NMinimize with `eqs// Rationalize[#, 0] & ` and `, WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxIterations -> 1000 `   to get `BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, O21] /. %[[2]] `  `(*   1.*10^-12   *) `

Comment: `sol = NMinimize[{MU, (BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, 
        O21] == 10^(-12) // Rationalize[#, 0] &) && MU > 100 && MU < 100000 && Ms > 100 && Ms < 100000 && O11 > -1 && O11 < 1 && O12 > -1 && O12 < 1 && O21 > -1 && O21 < 1 && O11 != 0 &&  VU11 > -1 && VU11 < 1 && VU11 != 0 && VU12 > -1 && VU12 < 1 && 
    VU21 > -1 && VU21 < 1 && VU21 <= Sqrt[1 - VU11^2] && 
    VU12 <= Sqrt[1 - VU11^2]}, {MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, 
   O21}, WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxIterations -> 1000]
BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU11, VU12, VU21, O11, O12, O21] /. sol[[2]]`