# NMinimize subject to many complicated conditions not obbeying imposed equation

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

This question derives from (and refers to) [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237771/find-instance-of-equation-that-also-minimizes-one-variable/237777?noredirect=1#comment601003_237777) one asked by me, and I hope that creating a new question rather than editing that one is appropriate. There I ask for a way to find the subset of the solution of some equation that is also a global minimum of some variable. My current notebook to that end is the following (which I paste entirely to allow reproduction)

```
Alfa = 1/137;
sw = Sqrt[0.23152];
m\[Mu] = 105.658*10^-3 (*GeV*);
m\[Tau] = 1.77682 (*GeV*);



\[CapitalGamma]\[Mu] = 1/(3.34*10^18);
\[CapitalGamma]\[Tau] = 1/(4.41*10^11);



gs = 1;
gU = 1/Sqrt[2] Sqrt[4  Pi Alfa]/sw;

BRfunction[MU_, Ms_, VU1x1_, VU1x2_, VU2x1_, Oss1x1_, Oss1x2_, 
   Oss2x1_] := (1/\[CapitalGamma]\[Mu])*(
   m\[Mu]^5 (1/
       5 gs^4 MU^4 Oss1x1^2*(Oss1x2^2 + Oss2x1^2) (15 Ms^2 - 
         2 m\[Mu]^2) + 
      4 gs^2 gU^2 Ms^4 MU^2 VU1x1*
       Oss1x1*(VU1x2*Oss1x2 + VU2x1*Oss2x1) + 
      2 gU^4 Ms^6 VU1x1^2*(VU1x2^2 + VU2x1^2)))/(
   6144 \[Pi]^3 Ms^6 MU^4);
BRfunctionTau[MU_, Ms_, VU1x1_, VU1x3_, VU3x1_, Oss1x1_, Oss1x3_, 
   Oss3x1_] := (1/\[CapitalGamma]\[Tau])*(
   m\[Tau]^5 (1/
       5 gs^4 MU^4 Oss1x1^2*(Oss1x3^2 + Oss3x1^2) (15 Ms^2 - 
         2 m\[Tau]^2) + 
      4 gs^2 gU^2 Ms^4 MU^2 VU1x1*
       Oss1x1*(VU1x3*Oss1x3 + VU3x1*Oss3x1) + 
      2 gU^4 Ms^6 VU1x1^2*(VU1x3^2 + VU3x1^2)))/(
   6144 \[Pi]^3 Ms^6 MU^4);

minelOss = 10^-4;
minelVU = 10^-3;

AssumptionsAbsoluteBounds = 
  And[VU1x1 < 1, VU1x1 > -1, VU1x2 < 1, VU1x2 > -1, VU2x1 < 1, 
   VU2x1 > -1, Oss1x1 < 1, Oss1x1 > -1, Oss1x2 < 1, Oss1x2 > -1, 
   Oss2x1 < 1, Oss2x1 > -1, VU1x3 < 1, VU1x3 > -1, VU3x1 < 1, 
   VU3x1 > -1, Oss1x3 < 1, Oss1x3 > -1, Oss3x1 < 1, Oss3x1 > -1, 
   MU > 100, Ms > 100];

AssumptionsLowestModulus = 
  And[Abs[Oss1x1] > minelOss, Abs[Oss1x2] > minelOss, 
   Abs[Oss2x1] > minelOss, Abs[Oss1x3] > minelOss, 
   Abs[Oss3x1] > minelOss, Abs[VU1x1] > minelVU, Abs[VU1x2] > minelVU,
    Abs[VU2x1] > minelVU];

Assumption\[Tau]ExpBound = 
  And[BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU1x1, VU1x3, VU3x1, Oss1x1, Oss1x3, 
     Oss3x1] < 10^-8];

Assumption\[Mu]ExpBound = 
  And[BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU1x1, VU1x2, VU2x1, Oss1x1, Oss1x2, 
     Oss2x1] == 10^(-12)];

AssumptionsVUUnit = 
  And[Abs[VU1x2] == Sqrt[1 - VU1x1^2 - VU1x3^2], 
   Abs[VU2x1] == Sqrt[1 - VU1x1^2 - VU3x1^2]];

Sol = NMinimize[{MU, (Assumption\[Mu]ExpBound // 
      Rationalize[#, 0] &) && (Assumption\[Tau]ExpBound // 
      Rationalize[#, 0] &) && 
    AssumptionsAbsoluteBounds && (AssumptionsLowestModulus // 
      Rationalize[#, 0] &) && (AssumptionsVUUnit // 
      Rationalize[#, 0] &)}, {MU, Ms, VU1x1, VU1x2, VU2x1, VU1x3, 
   VU3x1, Oss1x1, Oss1x2, Oss2x1, Oss1x3, Oss3x1}, 
  Method -> Automatic, MaxIterations -> 10000, WorkingPrecision -> 80]
```

The problem is that this doesn't work! That is, the solution found by `NMinimize` disobbeys the equation

```
BRfunction[MU, Ms, VU1x1, VU1x2, VU2x1, Oss1x1, Oss1x2, Oss2x1] == 10^(-12)
```

by a lot -- if calculated on the solution `BRfunction` gives something to the order of 10^(-7) at best.

It may be theorized that this is because the set of constraints does not have a solution -- but simply increasing MU and Ms (always found by NMinimize to be to the order of 100) to a few thousands shows that it does.

How can I fix it? Could it be because of number precision in the definitions?

Comment: Have you tried different methods in NMinimize? Maybe the automatically chosen method doesn’t work as well in your case. See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html

Comment: @MarcoB None of the methods seems to work, unfortunately

Comment: Although `RandomSearch` seems to do better than the others. In any case, I do believe that some smart changes to the programing are necessary

Comment: I'd try changing the inputs to be either exact or high precision, and changing the `WorkingPrecision` and perhaps also the two `XXXGoal` settings. Also you might take the result from `NMinimize` and see if it can be refined using as a starting value for `FindMinimum.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you! Doesn't the `Rationalize[#,0] &` achieve this goal of making the constraints exact? If not, how would be the simplest way for me to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Rationalize` that way to make them exact.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau In this case it is not enough. Also, since there is no standard way to initialize a specific starting point for NMinimize, I assume you are suggesting that I decrease the number of variables fixing some of them? That would defeat my purpose. Do you have any more suggestions? I am somewhat desperate. Thank you again!

Comment: I was suggesting as one possibility that the values be used to initialize `FindRoot`.